# Find all feature in Lucene

Tags: lucene

I have the following two fields on my web page: `BookAuthor` and `BookDescription`.  On submit, the page searches against Lucene index using the given search criteria.

If the user does not type in anything in the two fields and submits the page, how do I make Lucene.Net return all the books from my index irrespective of `BookAuthor` and `BookDescription` field values?

Answer (score 1):

The common solution here is to add another field to every document in your index. It's a fake field, like "ALL_RECORDS", that contains some dummy value, like "x". Lucene won't take an empty query, so if a user tries to perform one, your application replaces it with a query like "ALL_RECORDS:x", which returns every record.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [MatchAllDocsQuery](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/docs/2.1/Lucene.Net.Search.MatchAllDocsQuery.html).